# Using custom streambuf with boost::asio async operations

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing a server application using boost::asio.
I am reading known amount of data from user and write it to a data sink which has following api:

```
class Sink {
    ...
    void write(const char *data, size_t size);
}
```

The data is big and it is possible to call `write(..)` multiple times to process one stream.
In my code I would like to call:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket, sink_buffer,
    boost::asio::transfer_exactly(size), ...);
```

Is it possible to wrap `Sink` with custom `std::streambuf` or `boost::asio::basic_streambuf` so it could handle writing data parts to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects being passed as the *buffers* argument for `async_read()`, the *buffers* argument either :

- needs to be a type that meets the [`MutableBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html) requirement.
- be a `boost::asio::basic_streambuf` object.

Thus, it is possible to write a custom class that interacts with a `Sink` object when reading occurs.  However, the `boost::asio::basic_streambuf` does not appear to be designed to serve as a base class.

If `Sink::write` is only an abstraction to the underlying memory, consider using an approach similar to [`basic_streambuf::prepare()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/prepare.html), where a member function returns a handle to a buffer for a given size.  The underlying memory implementation would still remain abstracted behind the [`mutable_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html).  For example:

```
boost::asio::async_read( socket, sink.buffer( size ), ... );
```

If `Sink::write` has business logic, such as performing logic branching based on the value of certain bytes, then it may be required to pass an intermediate buffer to `async_read()`.  The invocation of `Sink::write()` with the intermediate buffer would then be done from within `async_read()`'s *handler*.  For example:

```
void handle_read_into_sink( boost::system::error_code error,
                            std::size_t bytes_transferred,
                            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket,
                            Sink& sink,
                            char* buffer,
                            std::size_t buffer_size,
                            std::size_t bytes_remaining,
                            boost::function< void() > on_finish )
{
  sink.write( buffer, buffer_size );

  bytes_remaining -= bytes_transferred;
  // If there are more bytes remaining, then continue reading.
  if ( bytes_remaining )
  {
    read_into_sink( socket, sink, buffer, buffer_size,
                    bytes_remaining, on_finish );
  }
  // Otherwise, all data has been read.
  else
  {
    on_finish();
  }  
}

void read_into_sink( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket,
                     Sink& sink,
                     char* buffer,
                     std::size_t buffer_size,
                     std::size_t bytes_remaining,
                     boost::function< void() > on_finish )
{
  boost::asio::async_read(
    socket, boost::asio::buffer( buffer , buffer_size ),
    boost::asio::transfer_exactly( buffer_size ),
    boost::bind( handle_read_into_sink,
                 boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                 boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                 boost::ref( socket ),
                 boost::ref( sink ),
                 buffer,
                 buffer_size,
                 bytes_remaining,
                 on_finish ) );
}
```

And begin the async read loop with:

```
read_into_sink( socket, sink, small_buffer, sizeof_small_buffer, 
                total_stream_size, read_handler_callback );
```

Make sure to check and handle *error* based on your desired logic.

Comment: Thanks for fast response.  My `Sink::write()` does not have any bussines logic. Problem is I cannot allocate memory for whole stream. I was hoping I would be able to allocate small buffer and pass data to `Sink::write()` whenever it overflows. This way one `boost::asio::async_read()` performs as many `Sink::write()`s as necessary and calls `ReadHandler` afterwards. I dont see how `MuttableBufferSequence` version could acomplish this.

Comment: I may not understand the context of overflow, but from the sounds of it, it could be resolved with an async_read loop that reads a small amount of data, writes to sink, and continues reading until the known stream size has been processed.  Once the entire stream has been processed, then it will call the desired `ReadHandler`.  The last part of my answer has been modified to demonstrate this.